# Record audio from usb microphone Android

Tags: android, usb, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a android tab(Samsung Tab S) running lollipop, when I connect a external usb Microphone(mono) to it for recording, android still uses inbuilt mic.

How can I record from external mic instead of inbuilt mic. Is it supported?

Comment: if you have already got the solution and reached next level : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154060/get-status-of-external-usb-microphone-connected-to-a-android-tab ,you can answer your own question,so that will be helpful to others